# web service for oauth 2.0 desktop and native mobile applications?

Tags: web-services, azure, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build an application that will use oauth 2.0 (with an secure token service and multiple idps) to handle authorization.

Currently my plan is to user thinktecture authorization server(oauth 2.0), Identity server(sts), and Azure access control service(idp for external identity providers) and Azure active directory(for internal logins).

QUESTION: Is there a pure cloud service where I can achieve oauth 2.0 sign on and custom scopes for all clients(web, native mobile, in-browser js)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [auth0.com](http://auth0.com)

DISCLAIMER:I work there.